# Create a position-mapped dictionary from a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of many many words.

From it, I want to create a dictionary which contains each unique word in the list as key, and the first position it appears in (the list index) as value of the key.

Is there an **efficient** method to do this?

Comment: Before asking for an *efficient* method, do you at least have a **working** one? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, I have some code which is trying to do something WITHOUT such a dictionary. That code would be better written WITH this dictionary, which is why I want it. But that code isn't relevant to the topic here, so I didn't post it.

Comment: What I've tried so far is a linear search through the list to extract the position of each word - a horrible method to be sure.

Comment: @Atriya you cannot do it faster than looking at every word, since you do not know what the words are before you do a linear search. To eliminate duplicates takes O(n*log(n)), so any solution in O(n) is faster anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
>>> import itertools as it
>>> dict(it.izip(reversed(l), reversed(xrange(len(l)))))
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 5}
```

Comment: Nah `zip` is cross compatible with `python 3` where it actually does return a generator. On that note you should probably use `range` instead of `xrange`.

Comment: Suggestion: use `reversed` instead of `[::-1]`

Comment: @RikPoggi Try it. I didn't think so at first.

Comment: @Marcin: It seems to return a `rangeiterator`, nice!

Answer (score 4):

Since you will have to look at every word anyways, it does not get faster than this:

```
index = {}

for position, word in enumerate(list_of_words):
    if word not in index:
        index[word] = position
```

Comment: How is this n^2? This is O(n) - for each of the *n* words in the list, this performs one or two constant time operations.

Comment: @eumiro this is O(n) since hashmaps have an amortized cost of O(1) for everything. It's exactly the same as your solution

Comment: @Marcin - oops, sorry, I was wrong. Of course, this is O(n) too.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
>>> dic = {l[i]:i for i in range(len(l)-1,-1,-1)}
>>> print(dic)
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @eumiro 's solution

```
>>> from itertools import count, izip
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
>>> dict(izip(reversed(l),count(len(l)-1,-1))) #In Py 3 just use zip
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 5}
```

Comment: This is what he had originally. The iterator version is slightly better on large lists, because it doesn't need to construct intermediate datastructures.

Comment: What do you mean it's better. This is just a different way of writing his first solution that seems cleaner to me. I'm not sure what you mean by `The iterator version is slightly better on large lists`. If you are referring to `izip` it can easy be changed to that for python 2.x.

Comment: I mean that it's better in that it will not create intermediate objects in either (major) version of python.

Comment: But it won't work in python 3 since `izip` has been changed to `zip`.

Comment: Then wrap the import in a `try`.

Comment: Nevermind i'll just change mine to use `izip` as well since python 2 is used by most people. Also i understand that iterators are more efficient, i was leaving it up to the user to use `izip` if they were using `python 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
l2 = set(l)
mydict = {v:l.index(v) for  v in   l2}
```

output

`{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 5}`